# How to highlight border color of input when on validation error in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```js
mobile: '',
  maxmobile: 10,

  validations: {


    mobile: {
     
    },
  }
```

```html
<input class="input-mobile ml-10" type="text" placeholder="Your mobile number" id="mobile" name="mobile" v-model="mobile" v-on:keypress="isMobileLanding($event)" :maxlength="maxmobile" v-model.trim="$v.mobile.$model" v-bind:class="{'input-color-change': $v.mobile.$invalid}"
  @input="$v.mobile.$touch" />

<p v-if="$v.mobile.$dirty">
  <span class="form__alert" v-if="!$v.mobile.numeric">Must be numeric.</span>
  <span class="form__alert" v-if="$v.mobile.numeric && !$v.mobile.between">
        Must be between {{$v.mobile.$params.between.min}} and {{$v.mobile.$params.between.max}}.
      </span>
</p>
```

How to highlight border color of input on validation error in Vue.js?

At present I'm having an issue with my code. Initially, the input border is highlighted, but I want to highlight it only if user enters a mobile number with less than 10 digits. If the user enters all 10 digits, the border color should not appear.

Comment: When showing code please provide all the code. e.g. `isMobileLanding`

Comment: Hi, Try using class binding.

Comment: @MichaelMano I have provided code for isMobileLanding(), I am generally checking for regex

Comment: @YashMaheshwari i have updated my code in question, Even i tried with v-bind class also but its not, Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<template>
  <input
    id="mobile"
    v-model="mobile"
    v-model.trim="$v.mobile.$model"
    :class="['input-mobile ml-10', mobileIsValid ? null : 'input-color-change']"
    type="text"
    placeholder="Your mobile number"
    name="mobile"
    :maxlength="maxmobile"
    @keypress="isMobileLanding($event)"
  />
  <div v-if="!mobileIsValid" class="error-messages">
    Kindly check phone is above {{ validations.mobile.minLength }} and blow
    {{ validations.mobile.maxLength }}.
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      maxmobile: 10,
      mobile: '',
      validations: {
        mobile: {
          required,
          minLength: minLength(10),
          maxLength: maxLength(9),
        },
        email: {
          required,
          email,
          maxLength: maxLength(30),
        },
      },
    }
  },
  computed: {
    mobileIsValid() {
      return (
        this.mobile.length >= this.validations.mobile.minLength &&
        this.mobile.length <= this.validations.mobile.maxLength
      )
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: Getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'mobile' of undefined. Which mentioned in error message div  in this line  validations.mobile.minLength

Comment: This example do have several root elements tho.

Comment: @kissu depends on vue version e.g. 3 several roots is fine. Also i was not expecting them to copy paste code. just a general idea on how to do it.

Comment: @mich yes and yes.